# Using Both Alternative Dates and Airports in Bargain Finder Max and Getting More Results

Tags: sabre

I'm currently testing with the Bargain Finder Max REST API.  I'm aware that there are versions of the BFM API specifically implementing alternative dates and alternative airports, but I was wondering if there was a way to combine alternative dates and alternative airports into a single request.  I've tried things like

```
{
 "OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ": {
   "AvailableFlightsOnly": true,
   "POS": {
        "Source": [{
            "PseudoCityCode":"F9CE",
            "RequestorID": {
                "Type": "1",
              "ID": "1",
                "CompanyName": {
                    "Code": "TN",
                 "CodeContext": "Context"
              }
         }
     }]
    },
    "OriginDestinationInformation": [{
      "DepartureDateTime": "2018-04-07T00:00:00",
       "OriginLocation": {
         "LocationCode": "DTW"
     },
        "DestinationLocation": {
            "LocationCode": "ORD"
     }
 }],
    "TravelerInfoSummary": {
        "AirTravelerAvail": [{
          "PassengerTypeQuantity": [{
             "Code": "ADT",
                "Quantity": 1
           }]
        }],
       "PriceRequestInformation": {
            "CurrencyCode": "USD"
     }
 },
    "TPA_Extensions": {
     "IntelliSellTransaction": {
         "RequestType": {
                "Name": "AD1"
         }
     }
  }
 }
}
```

But this only returns alternate dates for DTW -> ORD, the original origin and destination airports.

I'm also trying to figure out how to get more results with the alternative date BFM API.  Running the query

```
{
 "OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ": {
   "AvailableFlightsOnly": true,
   "POS": {
        "Source": [{
            "PseudoCityCode":"F9CE",
            "RequestorID": {
                "Type": "1",
              "ID": "1",
                "CompanyName": {
                    "Code": "TN",
                 "CodeContext": "Context"
              }
         }
     }]
    },
    "OriginDestinationInformation": [{
      "DepartureDateTime": "2018-04-07T00:00:00",
       "OriginLocation": {
         "LocationCode": "DTW"
     },
        "DestinationLocation": {
            "LocationCode": "ORD"
     }
 }],
     "TravelPreferences": {
        "TPA_Extensions": {
         "NumTrips": {
            "Number": 100
         }
        }
     },
    "TravelerInfoSummary": {
        "AirTravelerAvail": [{
          "PassengerTypeQuantity": [{
             "Code": "ADT",
                "Quantity": 1
           }]
        }],
       "PriceRequestInformation": {
            "CurrencyCode": "USD"
     }
 },
    "TPA_Extensions": {
     "IntelliSellTransaction": {
         "RequestType": {
                "Name": "AD1"
         }
     }
  }
 }
}
```

But this only returns one itinerary per day.

Could anyone help me with these issues?  Thanks kindly in advance!

Answer (score 0):

When doing BFM you have different qualifiers that may help with searching for alternate airports, like *AlternateAirportCities* or *SisterDestinationLocation*, but these don't seem to be enabled for BFM Alternate Dates.

Instead, what you may use instead of the airport codes, is the actual city where it present. In your example you go from Detroit (DTW) to Chicago (ORD), but if you change, for example, the destination to Chicago city (CHI) you can get  CHICAGO OHARE (ORD) as well as CHICAGO MIDWAY (MDW).

A few examples:

- LON instead of LHR, LCY, LGW
- NYC instead of JFK, LGA, EWR
- PAR instead of CDG, ORY
- MOW instead of DME, SVO, VKO
- BUE instead of EZE, AEP
- WAS instead of DCA, IAD